# Raise ValueError not working

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a Python function to extract numbers out of a string with regex. In some cases, the group I am identifying ("group1") is not found. In the next step of the code, I want to exclude those cases where it is not found, and otherwise clean the data further by excluding specific characters I iterate through. As seen in my code below, despite trying to both raise an AttributeError or return None in the case of None, I continue to get the error below:

```
if pre_clean.group('group1') is None:
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Does anyone know how I can successfully raise an error in the None cases and otherwise continue going through the code? Thank you.

```
def parse_string(input):

    parse_reg = '''
       ^(?P<group1> \(\d{6}\)\s* 
       [-]*
       (?P<group2>\d{10})
       (?P<group3>\d{2}) '''

    re_parsecmp=re.compile(parse_reg)
    pre_clean = re_parsecmp.match(input)

    'Clean area codes to just digits'
    deletechars='-(*)&' #charts to remove
    if pre_clean.group('group1') is None:
        raise AttributeError
        #return None
    pre_clean2=phone_parts.group('area_code')
    pre_clean3=pre_clean2.strip()
    for char in deletechars:
        pre_clean3 = pre_clean3.replace(char,"")
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward.  ```re_parsecmp.match(input)``` is returning None.

Comment: Exceptions should not be raised without necessity. Why raise an exception, if you can simply return from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a check on `pre_clean` first before invoking a method on it

```
if pre_clean is None or pre_clean.group('group1') is None:
        raise AttributeError
```

this is self explanatory and you wont get the same error you encountered.

Comment: Thank you. I did not understand that the error was happening in the matching step. Thank you.